# How to delete spaces from selected lines

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a little problem in Linux with removing spaces from selected lines from my file.

For example:

```
f h t s q e g h c h t
f h t r f h v f d g n
q a z x s w e d c v f
f h b c h t h b v h f
p l k o i j u h y g t
t f r d c v b h n j u
```

and now, how should I delete spaces from lines number 2, 4 and 5? Additionally, how's it going to look for the third line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using awk

To remove blanks from lines 2, 4, and 5:

```
$ awk 'NR==2 || NR==4 || NR==5 {gsub(/ /,"");} 1' file 
f h t s q e g h c h t
fhtrfhvfdgn
q a z x s w e d c v f
fhbchthbvhf
plkoijuhygt
t f r d c v b h n j u
```

In awk, `NR` is the line number.  The logical expression `NR==2 || NR==4 || NR==5` selects the lines of interest to you.  The command `gsub(/ /,"")` removes blanks from those lines.  The condition `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.

#### Using sed

To remove blanks from lines 2, 4, and 5:

```
$ sed '3n; 2,5 s/ //g' file 
f h t s q e g h c h t
fhtrfhvfdgn
q a z x s w e d c v f
fhbchthbvhf
plkoijuhygt
t f r d c v b h n j u
```

Here, we use slightly different logic: we remove blanks for all lines from 2 to 5 except line 3.  This works as follows:  the expression `3n` tells sed that, when it comes to line 3, print it and skip to the next line.  Otherwise, the command `2,5 s/ //g tells sed to remove blanks from all lines from 2 to 5.

#### To remove all whitespace, not just blanks

```
awk 'NR==2 || NR==4 || NR==5 {gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"");} 1' file
```

Or:

```
sed '3n; 2,5 s/[[:space:]]//g' file
```

Comment: I need "sed" version, but I have also another question: How it's gona look like for third line?

Comment: OK.  The sed version leaves the third line unchanged.  (For the third line, the `n` command is used.  This causes sed to print that line unchanged and move on.)

Comment: `$ sed 'n; 3 s/ //g' file` Is it ok?

Comment: @warszawiaczek That command would leave all lines unchanged.  That is because `n` tells sed to skip the rest of the commands and, consequently, the `3 s/ //g` command would never be executed.

Comment: sooooooo `$ sed '3n; 3 s/ //g' file` remove all blanks in third line?

Comment: @warszawiaczek That again leaves the file unchanged.  What problem do you want to solve?  If you want to remove the blanks from line 3 only, then use `sed '3 s/ //g' file`.  If you want to remove all blanks from lines 2 through 5, then use `sed '2,5 s/[[:space:]]//g' file`.

Comment: Okkkk now I understand everything! Really sorry and thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Other variant for `awk`

```
awk 'NR~/^[245]$/{$1=$1}1' OFS='' file
```

Comment: the answer has it too but what is the '1' before the OFS doing ? It doesn't work without it ?

Comment: @Bor From **man awk**: *One, but not both, of `pattern {action}` can be omitted.   If `{action}` is omitted it is implicitly `{ print }`*. So in the case *pattern* == 1 (mean *true for each line*) and *action* is omitted that is mean *`{ print }`*. In other word `1` is shortening `True { print $0 }`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a shell. It might even be worth doing that way in some cases. Probably not often, though.

```sh
sh -fc  <in >out '
    for IFS do read -r l
        printf %s $l;echo
    done; exec cat
' -- '' \  '' \  \
```

---

```
f h t s q e g h c h t
fhtrfhvfdgn
q a z x s w e d c v f
fhbchthbvhf
plkoijuhygt
t f r d c v b h n j u
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lpe 'grep { /^$.$/ } (2,4,5) and s/\s//g'
```

or with the experimental *smartmatch operator* :

```
perl -lpe '$. ~~ [2,4,5] and s/\s//g'
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'NR==2 || NR==4 || NR==5{gsub(/\s/, "")} 1' file
```

#### Output :

```
 f h t s q e g h c h t
fhtrfhvfdgn
 q a z x s w e d c v f
fhbchthbvhf
plkoijuhygt
 t f r d c v b h n j u
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody needed to represent 'tr' properly, declare a solution therewith, so here goes:

```
 tr -d [:space:]
```

OR

```
 tr -d [:blank:]
```

Assuming the text source is a file called ich:

```
 cat ich | tr -d [:space:]
```

This produces one line, no space:

fhtsqeghchtfhtrfhvfdgnqazxswedcvffhbchthbvhfplkoijuhygttfrdcvbhnju

If you wish to preserve the lines, then employ this variant:

```
 cat ./ich | tr -d [:blank:]
```

which produces this output ( minus the extra newline between the lines )

fhtsqeghcht

fhtrfhvfdgn

qazxswedcvf

fhbchthbvhf

plkoijuhygt

tfrdcvbhnju

Brilliant answers, my esteemed peers, each and every one!

F.